# nosetests RuntimeWarning for AnswerTesting when plugin not requested

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

I receive this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395: RuntimeWarning: Unable to load plugin answer-testing = yt.utilities.answer_testing.framework:AnswerTesting: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%s_%s'
  RuntimeWarning)
```

when running nosetests inside a docker container despite not requesting any plugins. I cannot find any reference on my system to `AnswerTesting` or `yt`. How can I fix the error or suppress it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the error, it is just the warning suggesting that you would not be able to use answer-testing plugin with nose. If it bothers you, remove it with pip, i.e.:

```
pip uninstall answer-testing
```

Or remove it manually by looking through `Lib/site-packages/easy-install.pth` for something like `./answer-testing-0.0.1-py3.4.egg` or similar.

If you are brave/lost, add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/plugins/manager.py:395` and see what is causing you grief.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error.

I had to

> pip install --upgrade cython

then

> pip install --upgrade yt

The error went away after that.  I could not simply install yt as it required an up to date cython.